# How do I escape colons in an attribute name with Python's ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, escaping, python-2.6, elementtree

### Background

I am using ElementTree in Python version 2.6 to create an XML file (using data retrieved from a database).

### Code

The following line of code is the problem area, as I keep getting a syntax error because of the colons within my attribute names.

```
# Please ignore any errors the "^" characters would cause if they were
# actually part of my code - just using them as placeholders.

root = ET.Element("databaseConfiguration", xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                                                ^
                  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="database.xsd")
                     ^
```

## Question

What is the most efficient way to escape the colons in these attribute names in order to have `root` equivalent to the following:

`<databaseConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="database.xsd"/>`

## Notes

I've looked at a few solutions on Stack Overflow (e.g. [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972210/escaping-characters-in-a-xml-file-with-python), [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367590/elementtree-will-not-parse-special-characters-with-python-2-7), [solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134658/tags-with-in-name-in-lxml) and [solution4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949092/parse-xml-with-prefixs-on-tags-xml-etree-elementtree)) where users were parsing an XML file, but I cannot seem to interpret these fixes as ones that would work for writing to an XML.

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: @VivekSable Haha thank you :) I'm a tad OCPD

Comment: can u check `>>> root = ET.Element("databaseConfiguration", {"xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"database.xsd"})
` is working or not?

Comment: @VivekSable Yes! That definitely worked. I was trying to use those curly brackets before but wasn't sure of the syntax. I'm not sure which implementation is better - this one or Daniel's?

Comment: yes, I also do not no much about this. I read from  the  http://lxml.de/tutorial.html , can u look this site also?

Comment: @VivekSable Thanks! I see what it's doing now. I still don't know what the asterisks in Daniel's answer are doing though. Oh well, they both seem to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72083/discussion-between-vivek-sable-and-kim-arundale).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

may be following will work for you.
Read from the [link](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

```
>>> root = ET.Element("databaseConfiguration", {"xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"database.xsd"})
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a dictionary

```
root = ET.Element("databaseConfiguration", **{'xmlns:xsi':"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
               'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation':"database.xsd"})
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, what is the difference between your answer and what Vivek suggested: `>>>root = ET.Element("databaseConfiguration", {"xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"database.xsd"})` **e.g. what do the extra asterisks do?**