# How to add xml tag which contains ":" in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have to add tag which contains a colon ':' symbol, but python does not like it:

The code I have is:

```
temp = etree.SubElement(OTHER, 'IDS:OwnedPropertyRentNetCust')
    temp.text = 'true'
```

It returns next error:

```
Invalid tag name u'IDS:OwnedPropertyRentNetCust'
```

How do I create an element with a colon?

Final tag has to be:

```
<IDS:OwnedPropertyRentNetCust>
```

Comment: Please see the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349579/python-elementtree-does-not-like-colon-in-name-of-processing-instruction

Comment: How did you add the ':' to your xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML elements that have the colon `:` are bound to a namespace and are using a namespace-prefix. The value before the `:` is the namespace-prefix, which is like a variable referencing a namespace value.

There are a couple of ways to create an element bound to a namespace.

Instead of a string for the element name, you can provide a [QName()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#qname-objects):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
IDS_NS   =  "http://whatever/the/IDS/namespace/value/is" #adjust this to the real IDS NS
ET.register_namespace("IDS", IDS_NS) 
et.SubElement(root, et.QName(IDS_NS, "OwnedPropertyRentNetCust"))
```

Use [Clark notation](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm#element-tree-representation), which includes the namespace and the element's `local-name()` in the string value:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
IDS_NS   =  "http://whatever/the/IDS/namespace/value/is"
ET.register_namespace("IDS", IDS_NS) 
et.SubElement(root, "{http://whatever/the/IDS/namespace/value/is}OwnedPropertyRentNetCust")
```

Comment: this will add a xmlns: to tag, I don't need it.

Comment: In order for an element to have an XML namespace prefix, it must be bound to a namespace (even if that is empty), or it must be declared on an ancestor element. If not, then it isn’t valid we’ll-formed XML and will have a hard time trying to make it with XML apis

Comment: How did you add the ':' to your xml?